# show classes as dropdown in guttenberg`s additional css classes input box

Tags: css, block-editor

I have set some css classes for the boxes in the Gutenberg editor, and I can type it in the additional css input box, it is not a problem for me, but for the client it is not convenient, because he does not know and he forget them. There is a way to have a drop-down with all the custom classes instead of a simple input field?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should add a custom plugin. That needs a PHP main file that includes and registers a JavaScript file. The source below should result in a plugin. You will find a usable solution also in the probs below.

### PHP part

```
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'my_gutenberg_scripts' );
function my_gutenberg_scripts() {

    wp_register_script(
        'my-editor-enhancement',
        plugins_url( 'editor.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-blocks' ), // Necessary script handles.
        filemtime( plugins_url( 'editor.js', __FILE__ ) ),
        true
    );
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-editor-enhancement' );
}
```

### JavaScript part

In our example is this the code of the `editor.js`, that we enqueue above. The example add only one paragraph and two different heading types.

```
wp.domReady( () => {

    wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle( 'core/paragraph', {
        name: 'blue-paragraph',
        label: 'Blue Paragraph'
    } );

    wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle( 'core/heading', {
        name: 'default',
        label: 'Default',
        isDefault: true,
    } );

    wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle( 'core/heading', {
        name: 'alt',
        label: 'Alternate',
        isDefault: false,
    } );

} );
```

If you add `isDefault: true`, then this style will be marked as active on visible blocks that don’t already have a style specified.

#### core blocks

- `core/paragraph`
- `core/image`
- `core/heading`
- `core/gallery`
- `core/list`
- `core/quote`
- `core/audio`
- `core/cover`
- `core/file`
- `core/video`
- `core/preformatted`
- `core/code`
- `core/freeform`
- `core/html`
- `core/pullquote`
- `core/table`
- `core/verse`
- `core/button`
- `core/columns`
- `core/media-text`
- `core/more`
- `core/nextpage`
- `core/separator`
- `core/spacer`
- `core/shortcode`
- `core/archives`
- `core/categories`
- `core/latest-comments`
- `core/latest-posts`

---

## Removing blocks

#### JavaScript part

```
 wp.domReady( () => {
    wp.blocks.unregisterBlockStyle( 'core/button', 'default' );
    wp.blocks.unregisterBlockStyle( 'core/button', 'outline' );
    wp.blocks.unregisterBlockStyle( 'core/button', 'squared' );
} );
```

---

## Probs

- Automattic [Block Style Examples](https://github.com/Automattic/gutenberg-block-styles)
- Bill Eriksons [great post](https://www.billerickson.net/block-styles-in-gutenberg/).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find an alternative solution here:
https://www.billerickson.net/block-styles-in-gutenberg/

Comment: I add a longer answer that helps user to get a valid answer, also if we lost the source of the link.