# How to Add predefined CSS Classes to a Block using Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

im trying to add something like a select field to a Gutenberg Block, so the user can select wich class he wants for the block. The user should not type in a additional class, he should select from a predefined list wich class he wants.

Does someone know if there is a solution for that?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. As a rule plugin and theme recommendation questions are disliked here because they are so subjective that a definitive answer is hard to find. Currently, your question lacks focus. What have you tried so far and where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: Hello, my question has nothing to do with a plugin or a theme. Im working with the integrated block builder from Wordpress (Gutenberg) and I try to provide the block element group with a select field, so that the user can select predefined classes instead of writing his own classname. So far I've only managed to add one class for all group elements in the functions.php.

Comment: I do think the question is clear and not subjective, and I don't see how it lacks focus. I've been looking for the same thing: a menu where the user can choose an item and then one or multiple pre-defined classes are added to the currently selected block in the WordPress block editor.

Comment: This stackexchange topic should answer your need : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332531/show-classes-as-dropdown-in-guttenbergs-additional-css-classes-input-box